# Is there a way I can use the TailwindCSS peer marker for elements in different divs?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-elements

I have a form page where users get a form when they check the box for an apartment type and get a different one when they pick another.

```
<form class="" action="{% url 'requestservice:req_service' %}" method="POST">

                <input type="radio" id="single" value="SINGLE" class="peer/single"  name="property_type" checked />
                <label for="single" class="peer-checked/single:text-sky-500">Single Unit</label>
                        
                <input type="radio" id="multiple" value="MULTIPLE" class="peer/multiple"  name="property_type" />
                <label for="draft" class="peer-checked/multiple:text-sky-500">Multiple D. Unit</label>
            
                        
                <div class="hidden peer-checked/multiple:block  bg-white px-2 py-2 w-full space-y-2 md:space-y-3 rounded-xl">
                    <!--
                        <h3> M.D.U Unit Form </h3>
                    -->            
                    <div class="block">
                        <p class="font-medium text-gray-950 text-sm"> Name of property: </p>
                        <input type='text'  name="multiple_property_name" class="w-full p-1 focus:border-1 focus:outline-yellow-300 border border-red-100 shadow-md shadow-red-100 rounded-lg " placeholder="Property name">
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="font-medium flex space-x-5">
                        <p class="font-medium text-sm"> Central Server Room Avaliable: </p>
                        <input type="radio" name="central_server_room">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="block ">
                        <p class="font-medium text-sm"> Number of houses in MDU </p>
                        <input name="number_of_houses" placeholder="Number of houses" class="w-full p-1 focus:border-1 focus:outline-yellow-300 border border-red-100 shadow-md shadow-red-100 rounded-lg" type="number">
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                    
                <div class="hidden peer-checked/single:block bg-white px-2 py-2 space-y-2 w-full rounded-xl">
                    <!--
                        <h3> Single Unit Form </h3>
                    -->
                    <div class="block space-y-1">
                        <p class="font-medium"> Name of property: </p>
                        <input type='text' name="single_property_name" class="w-full p-1 focus:border-1 focus:outline-yellow-300 border border-red-100 shadow-md shadow-red-100 rounded-lg " placeholder="Property name">
                    </div> 
                </div>
            
                <div class="bg-inherit w-full h-3">

                </div>
                
                <div class="flex justify-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="bg-red-500  font-medium p-1 text-white text-center rounded-lg" value="Request Service">
                </div>

            
</form>
```

I implemented this using the `peer` markers in TailwindCSS and technically, it works.

The problem is I need to put the radio buttons and their labels in seperate divs then put the two divs in a another div so I can style the form the way I want but if I put these radio buttons (which are carrying the markers) or the sibling elements (the form divs I want to make visible or hidden based on their sibling's state), the `peer` marker no longer works and the form div just remain hidden.

Again, the form works but this issue is hindering me from styling the form the way I want.

How do i fix this using JUST TailwindCSS?

Answer (score 0):

For a strictly Tailwind-only solution, you could consider using the [`:has()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) though please be aware that there is no general support in Firefox at this time of writing.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<form class="" action="{% url 'requestservice:req_service' %}" method="POST">

  <div class="peer">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="single" value="SINGLE" class="peer/single" name="property_type" checked />
      <label for="single" class="peer-checked/single:text-sky-500">Single Unit</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="multiple" value="MULTIPLE" class="peer/multiple" name="property_type" />
      <label for="draft" class="peer-checked/multiple:text-sky-500">Multiple D. Unit</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden peer-[:has(#multiple:checked)]:block  bg-white px-2 py-2 w-full space-y-2 md:space-y-3 rounded-xl">
    <div class="block">
      <p class="font-medium text-gray-950 text-sm"> Name of property: </p>
      <input type='text' name="multiple_property_name" class="w-full p-1 focus:border-1 focus:outline-yellow-300 border border-red-100 shadow-md shadow-red-100 rounded-lg " placeholder="Property name">
    </div>

    <div class="font-medium flex space-x-5">
      <p class="font-medium text-sm"> Central Server Room Avaliable: </p>
      <input type="radio" name="central_server_room">
    </div>

    <div class="block ">
      <p class="font-medium text-sm"> Number of houses in MDU </p>
      <input name="number_of_houses" placeholder="Number of houses" class="w-full p-1 focus:border-1 focus:outline-yellow-300 border border-red-100 shadow-md shadow-red-100 rounded-lg" type="number">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="hidden peer-[:has(#single:checked)]:block bg-white px-2 py-2 space-y-2 w-full rounded-xl">
    <div class="block space-y-1">
      <p class="font-medium"> Name of property: </p>
      <input type='text' name="single_property_name" class="w-full p-1 focus:border-1 focus:outline-yellow-300 border border-red-100 shadow-md shadow-red-100 rounded-lg " placeholder="Property name">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bg-inherit w-full h-3">

  </div>

  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <input type="submit" class="bg-red-500  font-medium p-1 text-white text-center rounded-lg" value="Request Service">
  </div>


</form>
```

Alternatively, with a slightly more bending of your stipulations, you could consider having the `<input>` radios hidden and outside the `<div>`s, so that peer can still work. Instead, have custom radio buttons for appearances:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<form class="" action="{% url 'requestservice:req_service' %}" method="POST">

  <input type="radio" id="single" value="SINGLE" class="peer/single sr-only" name="property_type" checked />
  <input type="radio" id="multiple" value="MULTIPLE" class="peer/multiple sr-only" name="property_type" />

  <div class="group">
    <div>
      <label for="single" class="group-[#single:checked~&]:text-sky-500">
        <div class="w-[1em] h-[1em] border border-slate-800 rounded-full inline-block p-0.5 bg-clip-content group-[#single:checked~&]:bg-sky-500"></div>
        Single Unit
      </label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="multiple" class="group-[#multiple:checked~&]:text-sky-500">
        <div class="w-[1em] h-[1em] border border-slate-800 rounded-full inline-block p-0.5 bg-clip-content group-[#multiple:checked~&]:bg-sky-500"></div>
        Multiple D. Unit
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden peer-checked/multiple:block  bg-white px-2 py-2 w-full space-y-2 md:space-y-3 rounded-xl">
    <div class="block">
      <p class="font-medium text-gray-950 text-sm"> Name of property: </p>
      <input type='text' name="multiple_property_name" class="w-full p-1 focus:border-1 focus:outline-yellow-300 border border-red-100 shadow-md shadow-red-100 rounded-lg " placeholder="Property name">
    </div>

    <div class="font-medium flex space-x-5">
      <p class="font-medium text-sm"> Central Server Room Avaliable: </p>
      <input type="radio" name="central_server_room">
    </div>

    <div class="block ">
      <p class="font-medium text-sm"> Number of houses in MDU </p>
      <input name="number_of_houses" placeholder="Number of houses" class="w-full p-1 focus:border-1 focus:outline-yellow-300 border border-red-100 shadow-md shadow-red-100 rounded-lg" type="number">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="hidden peer-checked/single:block bg-white px-2 py-2 space-y-2 w-full rounded-xl">
    <div class="block space-y-1">
      <p class="font-medium"> Name of property: </p>
      <input type='text' name="single_property_name" class="w-full p-1 focus:border-1 focus:outline-yellow-300 border border-red-100 shadow-md shadow-red-100 rounded-lg " placeholder="Property name">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bg-inherit w-full h-3">

  </div>

  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <input type="submit" class="bg-red-500  font-medium p-1 text-white text-center rounded-lg" value="Request Service">
  </div>


</form>
```